# Trying to understand CBV's, but what is a good way to organize a single page with several models?

Tags: python, django

I know some about context data in views, but do you as a professional even use the built in CBV's, or how do you organize for example a profile app? In the profile view there can be one form for posting text, and one tag to display user details from a user model, and perhaps some other data from a profile model, and then maybe a list of the users friends and most popular posts and so on..

I find it really difficult to understand how to structure views for bigger projects. Are we not supposed to use ListView, CreateView, DetailView etc, in the same page, they are only for simple and fast usage for small websites?

What is the standard way of doing this? Do you know of any github projects that are good examples that is not too big for a beginner to read?

For example, below is how I structured a login and register view - it is most probably not solid code in the details, but in general looking at structure - is this normal for every similar situation?

```
class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/start.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            login_form = AuthForm(self.request.GET or None)
            register_form = UserCreationForm(self.request.GET or None)
            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['login_form'] = login_form
            context['register_form'] = register_form
            return self.render_to_response(context)


class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthForm
    template_name = 'main/start.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        login_form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)
        register_form = UserCreationForm()
        if login_form.is_valid():
            login(request, login_form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(login_form=login_form, ))


class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'main/start.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            register_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            login_form = AuthForm()
            if register_form.is_valid():
                register_form.save()
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(success=True))
            else:
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(
                        register_form=register_form,
                        login_form=login_form
                    )
                )
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CBV for it's own purpose. Basically, CBV is divied for several group - `List`, `Detail`, `Edit`, and so on. If you know about `REST`, you can understand django cbv is try to follow RESTful way. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

If your purpose is not matching to any of those CBV, you just can use Base CBV, `View`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

This fbv code will be...

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse('result')
```

in CBV. That's all. `ListView`, `DetailView` and other Views from django is well-made prepared views for common usage things. If you don't want, you can just not use it. Just use `View` with many models and many functinos is possible. (Although it's not that good single view.)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about REST! Very interesting.

Comment: I've been reading up on this now, and this was really a missing piece in my understanding, why isn't this the standard way, or is it? It feels like i have been trying to "fool the system". I will accept your answer for bringing to my attention this type of design.

Comment: It's good point. There's many ppl that thinking like you - they only use `View` for writing CBV. I can understand that way - more intuitive way. But as you know, python-django is for more effective. Also, RESTful way is one of standard way for web. (I guess you still have CRUD way in your single page) So django provide that way for more efficiency I guess. If you write ListView on your own way, it has lot more lines for simple `ListView` in CBV.

Answer (score 0):

The generic CBVs are designed for one model, but their logic can be used as examples for more complex pages.